# Finding time at which particle in electric and magnetic field attains minimum speed

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I am attempting the following problem. There is a charged particle of charge $q$ and mass $m$, in a region of space having electric field $-E\vec{z}$, magnetic field $B\vec{z}$ and an initial velocity $v_{0}\left(\cos\theta \vec{y}+\sin\theta\vec{z}\right)$. I have to determine the time at which the particle attains minimum speed.

I have arrived at the following results and the following set of differential equations but I am not sure how to solve these. Once these are solved, I know all I have to do is set $\left(v_{x}^2+v_{y}^2+v_{z}^2\right)'=0$ and solve for $t$. Could someone give any pointers on how to solve these differential equations.

> $$ ma_{x}=qv_{y}B \\ ma_{y}=-qv_{x}B$$

Comment: I think this question is more suitable for https://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, these are not ordinary differential equations. There are more than one independent variables involved.

Comment: Why is there no electric field in your differential equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me you forgot the third equation involving the electric field:

$$ma_{x}=qv_{y}B \\ ma_{y}=-qv_{x}B \\ ma_z = -qE$$

Also, note that

$$\left(v_{x}^2+v_{y}^2+v_{z}^2\right)'=2(v_x a_x + v_y a_y + v_z a_z) = 0$$

In other words, extremal speeds are attained when velocity and acceleration are perpendicular. Thus,

$$v_x v_y B - v_x v_y B - v_z E = - v_z E = 0$$

Hence when the $z$-component of the velocity is $0$, you should be in an extremum of the speed.

However, your $z$-component of speed is not necessarily zero. In fact, what will happen is that the particle will be accelerated in the electric field vertically, while the magnetic field will induce a circular motion. Hence, the particle will move on a helicoidal trajectory. The minimum speed is therefore at the beginning of the motion, but this is not a stationary point of the equations.